# How to feed input from multiple Shiny Widgets into one global reactive value?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny widget such that users can choose a value from one of several drop downs or type in their own value:

```
  textInput("select0", label = h5("Currently selected user")),
  actionButton("generateInsights", label = "Show info"),
  selectInput("select1", label = h5("Select high data volume user"), 
              choices = make_named_list(top_users$userid), 
              selected = 1),
  selectInput("select2", label = h5("Select new user"), 
              choices = make_named_list(new_users$objectid), 
              selected = 1)
```

I would then like to make an interface that is reactive to an adjustment in any of these values:

```
current_userid = ""

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  current_userid_reactive = reactive({
    print("current userid got updated inside reactive expression")
    return(current_userid)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    print("updating plot")
    user_data = get_user_data_from_user_id1(current_userid_reactive(), big_data)
    print(user_data)
    cat("number rows userdata is ", nrow(user_data))
    ggplot(data=user_data, aes(x=displaydate, y=measurementvalue, color=datatype)) +
      geom_point(size=.6) + geom_line(aes(displaydate, mav),color="black", size = .2) + 
      facet_grid(datatype ~ ., scales = "free_y", labeller=label_both) + labs(x = "time", y = "Measurement")
  })

  output$momentCountPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(get_user_moment_count(input$select, big_data))
  })

  output$carbCountPlott <- renderPlot({
    plot(get_user_carb_count(input$select, big_data))
  })

  output$activityCountPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(get_user_activity_count(input$select, big_data))
  })

  observe({
    current_userid <- input$select1
    cat("updated current_userid to ", current_userid)
  })

  observe({
    current_userid <- input$select2
    cat("updated current_userid to ", current_userid)
  })

  output$ui <- renderUI({
    h1(current_userid)
  })

})
```

**What I am trying to do is update the value of current_userid from either `input$select1` or `input$select2` and then replot regardless of whether the user selected a new value from one or the other of the selections.**

However, I am finding that the `observe` functions run as expected (when I make a drop down selection), but their adjustment of the global `current_userid` does not lead to any accompanying action in `current_userid_reactive` or in `output$distPlot`. **How can I achieve what I'm trying to do? Why doesn't this use of a `reactive` element work?**

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with observe event since reactive functions capture input changes and handle them. Try `current_userid <<- input$select1` for example?

Comment: @Gopala Thanks for your comment. What I am trying to do is update the value of current_userid from either input$select1 or input$select2 and then replot regardless of whether the user selected a new value from one or the other of the selections. I'll add that to my original question.

Comment: As @Gopala noted, you need to use the global assignment operator `<<-` to update global variables.